# Indentation of "if" in Ocaml under Emacs

Tags: emacs, ocaml, indentation

I am coding Ocaml with Emacs, at the moment the setting of the indentation of `if` gives the following:

```
if cond1 then e1 else
  if cond2 then e2 else
    if cond3 then e3 else
      e4
```

I would like to realize the same format as [Caml programming guidelines](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/guides/guidelines.en.html):

```
if cond1 then e1 else
if cond2 then e2 else
if cond3 then e3 else
e4
```

Could anyone tell me which parameter is related to that? Thank you

**Edit1:** here is my [.emacs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/647619/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong. Are you using the caml-mode from the OCaml distribution ? Because I do and it indents according to the programming guidelines without setting any parameter. That's what I have in my `.emacs` (the mode is installed in `~/.emacs.d/caml-mode`):

```
;; Caml mode
(setq load-path (cons "~/.emacs.d/caml-mode" load-path))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.ml[iylp]?" . caml-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(autoload 'caml-mode "caml" "Major mode for editing Caml code." t)
(autoload 'run-caml "inf-caml" "Run an inferior Caml process." t)
(autoload 'camldebug "camldebug" "Run the Caml debugger." t)
(if window-system (require 'caml-font))
```

If you are using tuareg-mode I cannot help you. Note however that, contrary to popular belief, the caml-mode from the distribution is perfectly fine and is still maintained by OCaml's authors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i just added my `.emacs`

Comment: Well you are using tuareg-mode. You may want to try caml-mode (located in the emacs directory of the distribution). See my updated response to see what I have in my .emacs. If you are using a recent distribution you can remove all other things from your .emacs (e.g. caml-change-error-alist-for-backtraces and caml-change-error-alist-for-assert-failure)

Comment: Indeed, I decided to switch to `caml-mode`, but I do not like the font, do you have any suggestion to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763001/is-it-possible-to-use-the-font-of-tuareg-in-caml-mode-under-emacs)?

Comment: No, I just use the defaults. Regarding your problem about parts not hilighted, this shouldn't happen. Maybe you have a syntax error in your ocaml file. Also try to cleanup your `.emacs`, the hooks you install for caml-mode at the end are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use [ocp-indent](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent) which will (almost always) respect the Caml programming guidelines. The only difference is that it will indent the last expression, to avoid confusing scoping errors:

```
if cond1 then e1 else
if cond2 then e2 else
if cond3 then e3 else
  e4;
e5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable `tuareg-if-then-else-indent` to 0 which will then indent your example as

```
if cond1 then e1 else
if cond2 then e2 else
if cond3 then e3 else
e4
```

I don't know if that causes other undesirable indentation in case you don't have nested if's though.  You can also `M-x customize-group RET tuareg RET` to see all the indentation (and other) options.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not satisfied with the following?

```
if c1 then e1
else if c2 then e2
else if c3 then e3
else e4
```

Comment: I do not like that, as the guidelines suggest: "Lack of consistency in the treatment of all the conditions. Why a special case for the first condition?"