# Is it possible to use the font of tuareg in caml-mode under Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts, ocaml, tuareg

For [Indentation of “if”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751158/indentation-of-if-in-ocaml-under-emacs), i have to use `caml-mode` under Emacs.

But I find the font of `tuareg` is more colorful than `caml-font`, so my question is whether it is possible to use the font of `tuareg` in `caml-mode`.

Also, with the current [.emacs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/648260/) which requires `caml-font`, when I open a `.ml` file, some lines (especially in the beginning of the file) are not highlighted. If I go to those lines, modify them, they will change their color. Could anyone tell me how to fix that problem?

Also, do you have some better fonts for ocaml programs to suggest, besides the one of `tuareg` and `caml-font`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you like the colors better or that their are more colors?

If the latter, it's probably difficult to use tuareg font-locking with caml-mode, though I only looked at the two a little bit.

If it's the former, you can simply customize the faces used by `caml-mode` to use better faces (by which I mean typeface or "color").  With a sufficiently new emacs, put your cursor on the face that you want to change and type `M-x customize-face RET`.  It will suggest the name of the face that you are on, so hit return again.  Then you can change the face in any way you want.  As a first step you might keep `tuareg.el` open and check what faces are there, for example

```
(defface tuareg-font-lock-governing-face
  '((((background light)) (:foreground "blue" :bold t))
    (t (:foreground "orange" :bold t)))
  "Face description for governing/leading keywords."
  :group 'tuareg-faces)
```

is the definition of the face used for let, so you would just put your cursor on let, `M-x customize-face RET RET`, then change the foreground to blue and turn on bold (assuming you have a light background).  Don't forget to save it.

Alternately, you can edit `caml-font.el` and change the `caml-font-lock-keywords` section to use the fonts you like (which could be from tuareg).  If you want to add to your `.emacs` instead then you should change it to `(setq caml-font-lock-keywords ...)`.

```
(defconst caml-font-lock-keywords
  (list
   ...
;definition
   (cons (concat
          "\\<\\(a\\(nd\\|s\\)\\|c\\(onstraint\\|lass\\)"
          "\\|ex\\(ception\\|ternal\\)\\|fun\\(ct\\(ion\\|or\\)\\)?"
          "\\|in\\(herit\\|itializer\\)?\\|let"
          "\\|m\\(ethod\\|utable\\|odule\\)"
          "\\|of\\|p\\(arser\\|rivate\\)\\|rec\\|type"
          "\\|v\\(al\\(ue\\)?\\|irtual\\)\\)\\>")
         ;; 'font-lock-type-face)
         'tuareg-font-lock-governing-face)
   ...
   ))
```